# Different users on a SQL database seeing only their own datasets (C#, EF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a simple SQL Server database and want to connect to it with a C# application with Entity Framework. The migrations from EF works fine for me.

The user of the application connects to the database with his windows authentication.

There is one table with columns `ID | DATA | USERNAME`.

How can I prevent that users can see data from other users?

Sure, I can filter the data in the application itself and only present the allowed data to the user.

But the code of the application is open source (in public in source control) so that everyone can see the connection - and manual connect to the SQL Server reading all data.

So, my question: What is the best practice to hide each others data in the SQL Server but still allow the full functionality of EF like migrations?

Many Thanks - Konrad

Comment: could you post some code. What are you trying to hide and/or restrict?

Comment: What kind of “application”? A web service? A desktop application? The typical way of installing desktop applications it to install it per-user and store the application data in `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` so each user gets a separate database.

Answer (score 2):

You could add row level security on the database. This way only users who have created the rows can see them.

This way you would distribute logins to each user mapped to users in the database. The database will only return rows belonging to that user.

This wouldn't require any specific coding, it's all implemented server side.

SQL 2016 on wards though. It would be cool to implement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx

Comment: There are some security issues with this though: `It is possible to cause information leakage through the use of carefully crafted queries. For example, SELECT 1/(SALARY-100000) FROM PAYROLL WHERE NAME='John Doe' would let a malicious user know that John Doe's salary is $100,000. Even though there is a security predicate in place to prevent a malicious user from directly querying other people's salary, the user can determine when the query returns a divide-by-zero exception.`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than querying the table directly, create an object that filters by the username of the user.

```
WHERE Username = @Username
```

Use this in a function or stored procedure, passing the username of the person using the application as the input parameter.